# Check Name Availability of Azure Data Factory (ADF), Time Series Insights (TSI) and Stream Analytics Job resources

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-stream-analytics, azure-timeseries-insights

I am looking for a API or documentation for querying for name availability of Azure Data Factory (ADF), Time Series Insights (TSI) and Stream Analytics Job resources similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/vaults/checknameavailability.

I have tried looking at azure-arm-datafactory, azure-arm-streamanalytics node libraries but couldn't find functionality to check name availability of resources.

I am looking for something similar to below..

```
import KeyVaultMangementClient from 'azure-arm-keyvault';
const client = new KeyVaultMangementClient(this._credentials, this._subscriptionId);
        return client.vaults.checkNameAvailability({name: keyVaultName})
            .then((result: any) => {
                console.log(result.nameAvailable);
                return Promise.resolve(result.nameAvailable);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this (check name availability) feature is currently unsupported for ADF, TSI, Stream Analytics. So I would recommend you to please add a new feature request on [uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) with your suggestion(s) and let us know the link when you do it so that others can vote as well and which would in turn would raise visibility and priority on it.